# Visual Studio not debugging on crash

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging

This is driving me crazy. I'm working on a C# Forms application that is crashing for some reason when calling _documentList.Items.Clear();. For some reason, Visual Studio never catches the crash and it acts as if the application closed without any errors. I'm in the debugger stepping through line by line, and as soon as I hit the _documentList.Items.Clear();, the debugger stops and the form closes. Please help!

Edit: I've found why the app was crashing, but I'm still not sure why the debugger isn't catching it. This should have been much easier to find than it was.

I was trying to update my GUI from a FileSystemWatcher event, so I had to use this.InvokeRequired and this.Invoke(). I'm no longer getting the crash, but I would still like to know why VS isn't catching this in the debugger. My understanding is I should have been getting an exception with the message "Cross-thread operation not valid:"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that this is a known issue and has been fixed when using Tasks in .NET 4.0. See this question ([InvokeRequired Exception Handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3530011/invokerequired-exception-handling)) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I think we don't have listbox.Clear() it shopuld be listbox.Items.Clear();

Comment: You're correct of course, that was a type on my part. I've updated the question with the correct snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if the listbox have items before stepping into the line where you are clearing the items.
Check the items count of listbox.

Comment: Every time I process the directory to look for new files, I clear the listbox. When the app first starts it calls clear on an empty listBox, and that works fine. However when a file is deleted on the file system, it triggers a FileSystemWatcher event which kicks off the listBox.Items.Clear again, it's at that point that the app just closes.

Comment: I think the listbox instance becomes null, before you clear the listbox you check if its not eequal to null.

Comment: Nope, see my edits to find out what was causing the crash. I'm still looking for why Visual Studio debugger wasn't catching the problem.